# Can't find my app on App Store anymore

Tags: app-store

A few days ago my iPhone game has been approved for sale. When searching its name in the search bar of the App Store, it showed my App. Now when I try to search my game, it doesn't show any result. The direct link still works, however.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Search results/ranking changes. We can't help you with that. Contact Apple Developer Support if you think something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed by itself with time. I don't know why, but my application is appeared back in the search results of the App Store.

I suspect it was because of an internal trouble that Apple was having with the App Store servers at that time, maybe it erroneously removed my app record from the search database, and now they managed to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Check which country's App Store you are viewing currently. Probably it's not the same as the country your app is live now.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your support, but it was the same country. Now, for some obscure reason, my application has come back in the research terms.

Comment: What do you mean by _research terms_?

Comment: Sorry, bad translation from Italian. I mean the "search results"

Comment: ohh thats awesome!